# Will-change with SCSS in Jekyll

Tags: css, sass, jekyll, will-change

I am using Jekyll and Netlify to build a website. Everything has been working so far. I use a stylesheet in SCSS, which Jekyll converts to CSS at build. I experimented with adding the `will-change` property like the spec says to do it. However, the build failed with this error:

```
Invalid CSS after "... will-change": expected ";", was ": opacity, tran..." on line 1290
```

This is the SCSS I used that broke it:

```
#menuToggle {
...
    span {
            will-change: opacity, transform;
    }
...
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please let me know if there is more information that I ought to provide.

Comment: I guess that;s because will-change is not yet supported across all browsers and the build doesn't recognize it. https://caniuse.com/#search=will-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the issue is not with Jekyll or anything like that. I forgot to add a semicolon the end of the previous line. So lesson learned, if the error message is asking for a character, check to see if the previous code is missing it. My code sample really ought to include the context of the surrounding code a bit more, so that is another lesson learned.

Comment: Good catch! Copy-pasting is a bad practice in general but it might indeed help solving your issues on sites like this ;) Also, if you use an IDE like WebStorm (or a free alternative VSCode with plugins), the IDE will likely tell you exactly where these errors occur. Makes it easier to progress imho. Good luck!